# UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 1418-1419: surrogates not allowed

Tags: python

A variable called 'result' has data stored in the dataframe format.
The data is composed of Korean letters.
An error appears while converting this result to a csv file.
Why does this error appear and how can I solve it?

My codes are:

```
result.to_csv(f"{img_dir[:-4]}.csv", encoding='utf-8-sig', mode='w', index=False)
result
```

The errors appear like below:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 1418-1419: surrogates not allowed
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is good to post the code as text instead of an image.

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct UTF-8 and not other encoding such as johab, euc_kr, or cp949?

Comment: @SivaShanmugam Changed the post as text. Thanks!

Comment: @pepoluan Yes, the data is correct UTF-8 T.T

Comment: @JinsolKim hmmm, interesting ... if you can share one piece of problematic data here, preferably as a byte string (i.e., `b"..."`), maybe we can help you figure out what's wrong. No need for the whole data set, just one row / one field would be enough.

Comment: what is the value at position 1418 and 1419?? thats were the issue..